# switiching an input between high and low state with a trigger signal?

Tags: switches, cmos

I want to build an electronic analogue SPDT switch that switches on a trigger/rising edge.
A SPDT CMOS switch control is held high or low for either output.

This could be done with 2 outputs of a CD4017 + inverters to switch the switch states but there must be a more elegant solution than that.

Comment: Use an [analogue switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogue_switch) aka [transmission gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate).

Comment: @Jay does it toggle on rising edge or go to a particular state?  What is the maximum rate of rising edges, max clock rate?

Comment: @Jay could you not use a DFF, with /Q going to D input and your clk to clk?  Like SN74AUP1G80?

Comment: @scorpdaddy it should toggle. max clock rate... 10Hz? maybe a little higher, nothing high speed.

Flip flop seems like its the answer but the [logic](https://learnabout-electronics.org/Digital/images/D-Type-ff.gif) kinda confuses me.
clk rising edge > /Q goes high > D goes high > /Q goes low ... how would the next rising edge end up holding /Q high?

Comment: @scorpdaddy Did you mean to post a flip flop chip with Q and /Q outputs? A Toggle flip flop looks like it will do the trick.

Comment: Circuit like this: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-zDUdNkUKUgQ/Uy6zNHRekNI/AAAAAAAAA0Q/HXBZAWpDc7k/s1600/divided_by_2.png

Comment: @Jay When clk goes high the value at D input is clocked into the flip flop and eventually makes its way to the outputs.  This changes the input at D but the clk has already fired the flip flop and it's won't clock the new D in until the next rising edge.

Comment: Yeah, that's the ticket. Thanks for the help